# AppleScript to create aliases of files in a folder

Tags: applescript, finder, aliases

So I have this AppleScript for making aliases of all the contents of one folder to another folder.

I works perfectly unless there is only one item in the source folder.

```
tell application "Finder"
    set SourceFolder to (choose folder with prompt "Please choose Source folder:") as string
    set DestinationFolder to (choose folder with prompt "Choose Destination folder for aliases:") as string
    set theFolders to every item of entire contents of folder SourceFolder
    repeat with thisFolder in theFolders 
        set thisName to name of thisFolder
        make new alias file at folder DestinationFolder to thisFolder without invisibles
    end repeat
end tell
```

Any idea why it's not getting anything when there's one item only? When there's at least 2 items in the source folder it creates aliases for both in the destination.

On a side note, any way to get it to remember the source and destination folders between times you run it?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
property SourceFolder : missing value
property DestinationFolder : missing value

if SourceFolder = missing value then
    set SourceFolder to (choose folder with prompt "Please choose Source folder:")
    set DestinationFolder to (choose folder with prompt "Choose Destination folder for aliases:")
else

    tell application "Finder"
        set theFolders to every item of entire contents of SourceFolder as list
        repeat with thisFolder in theFolders
            make new alias file at DestinationFolder to thisFolder
        end repeat
    end tell
end if
```

Comment: Thank you! Works perfectly now. Any way to keep it from making aliases for invisible files?